# How can my player collides with the border of the canvas?

Tags: python, tkinter

The Player should collide with the border of the canvas, but I don't know how to do it.

```
from tkinter import *
import time
```

the window

```
tk = Tk()
tk.title("Game")
tk.geometry("500x500")
tk.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
tk.resizable(0, 0)
```

the canvas

```
canvas = Canvas(tk, width=500, height=500, bg="#FFD700")
canvas.pack()
canvasx = canvas.winfo_width()
canvasy = canvas.winfo_height()

player = canvas.create_rectangle(240, 240, 260, 260, fill="blue", 
outline="dark blue")
```

the Player class

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, event, canvas):
        def move(event):
            if event.keysym == "Up" or event.keysym == "w":
                canvas.move(1, 0, -5)
            elif event.keysym == "Down" or event.keysym == "s":
                canvas.move(1, 0, 5)
            elif event.keysym == "Right" or event.keysym == "d":
                canvas.move(1, 5, 0)
            else:
                canvas.move(1, -5, 0)
```

what should I write in this function?

```
        def hit_border():
            pass            

        canvas.bind_all("<KeyPress-Up>", move)
        canvas.bind_all("<KeyPress-w>", move)
        canvas.bind_all("<KeyPress-Down>", move)
        canvas.bind_all("<KeyPress-s>", move)
        canvas.bind_all("<KeyPress-Right>", move)
        canvas.bind_all("<KeyPress-d>", move)
        canvas.bind_all("<KeyPress-Left>", move)
        canvas.bind_all("<KeyPress-a>", move)
```

here is the loop that makes the everything work

```
while True:
    player = Player(canvas, canvas)
    tk.update()
    time.sleep(0.001)
```

Comment: Relevant [tkinter-moving-balls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44499813/tkinter-moving-balls-program-creating-4-balls-instead-of-2), read `def move_ball(`

Comment: It doesn't help me, because in his game the ball moves by itself, but in mine I make the Player move

Comment: *"moves by itself, but in mine I make the Player move"*: There is no difference. Your impossible, to detect the border, lies in your `def move(...`. You move without taking the current position in account. Change to: **1**: Get `coords(...`, **2**: Compute new `coord`, **3**: Compare with `border.bbox(...`, **4**. `if` outside, don't move `else` move.